# DataMapper: one to many relationship with one of several models?

Tags: ruby, orm, sinatra, datamapper

Here's my models:

```
class Item
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  has 1, :firstitem
  has 1, :seconditem
end

class FirstItem
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  belongs_to :item
end

class SecondItem
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  belongs_to :item
end
```

Now, my question is this - if I want `FirstItem` and `SecondItem` to be different models but want them both to potentially be part of `Item` (but only one of the two, so a record with  `FirstItem` will not also have a `SecondItem`), I could make a `has 1` relationship for both of them, and only one of them gets filled.

So in a relational database, does it make sense to do this? Is there a better, more efficient way of defining this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a polymorphic association, which sadly, DataMapper does not support. Try looking into ActiveRecord instead; you can easily use it with Sinatra.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know!